# Can't pip install pandas... error from a subprocess

Tags: python, pandas, installation, terminal, pip

I am trying to install pandas to use in my python code. I was able to upgrade my pip using `pip install upgrade pip` but when I try to install pandas using `pip install pandas` I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\compaq.py", line 78
      , in CompaqVisualFCompiler
        m.initialize()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\msvccompiler.py", line 48, in
     initialize
        _MSVCCompiler.initialize(self)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\msvccompiler.py", line 259, in initialize
        self.__paths = self.get_msvc_paths("path")
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\msvccompiler.py", line 602, in get_msvc_paths
        r"\Win32 (%s)\Directories" % (self.__root, platform))
    AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute '_MSVCCompiler__root'
 
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp94oxoujq_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp94oxoujq_in_process.py", line 345, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp94oxoujq_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tr54un10\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare
    e_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tr54un10\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 248, in run_se
    tup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tr54un10\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_se
    tup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 508, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 500, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup 
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tr54un10\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup   
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tr54un10\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\dist_info.py", line 31, in 
    run
        egg_info.run()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 24
    , in run
        self.run_command("build_src")
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 1
    44, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 1
    55, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 2
    88, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 3
    78, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 658, in get_mathlib_info
        st = config_cmd.try_link('int main(void) { return 0;}')
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\command\config.py", line 241, in 
    try_link
        self._check_compiler()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 80, 
    in _check_compiler
        self.fcompiler = new_fcompiler(compiler=self.fcompiler,
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\__init__.py", line 
    876, in new_fcompiler
        load_all_fcompiler_classes()
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\__init__.py", line 
    777, in load_all_fcompiler_classes
        __import__ (module_name)
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\compaq.py", line 54
    , in <module>
        class CompaqVisualFCompiler(FCompiler):
      File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i72pcle8\numpy_328f6081d36f426b90572be17f203722\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\compaq.py", line 83
    , in CompaqVisualFCompiler
        if '_MSVCCompiler__root' in str(msg):
    NameError: name 'msg' is not defined
    [end of output]
 
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: metadata-generation-failed
 
  Encountered error while generating package metadata.
 
  See above for output.
 
  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for details.
  [end of output]
    × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> See above for output.

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Before upgrading my pip, I tried installing pandas but none of the versions that I tried to install would download; however, I don't think I was getting these same errors before I upgraded pip. Can someone help me figure out how to install pandas? Is there a different way that I need to install it without using `pip install pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the NumPy then try to install pandas again.

> pip uninstall package_name

Comment: Thank you! I ended up completely uninstalling python, my IDE, and pip and then installing condas as my project manager instead. Afterward, I reinstalled my IDE and everything works now!

Comment: This just gives me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

Comment: Remove numpy and then remove pandas after that install pandas again

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Pycharm uses virtual environment(venv)
Each pycharm project creates its own virtual environment.
You are getting an error to use the package pandas because the package  isn't a part of your virtual environment.
To check the status of your virtual environment in pycharm press CTRL + ALT + S at the same time. It will open up a GUI, click the project and be sure to click the drop down and then click the Python Interpreter you will see all the packages installed on your system.  If you do not see the pandas package, click the +
and search for pandas  and then click install packages.